# Change button on click color with transparent button

Tags: java, android, button, transparency

I have an about 80 % transparent button in a `RelativeLayout` and the current theme is `Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar`. Now I want to change the highlight color if I click this button to another color than this blue.

So do I have to change the whole theme or is there a simple way to achieve this. I have already used `<item>`  from `drawable` with different status, but this isn't working, cause my transparency is lost if I set the new background to the button.

Comment: Try to use hex color. For example, you want black ("#000000"), to make it transparent do it like that: #55000000. The 55 part is an example. You can add numbers in front of the color t change it transparency. Try playing with some colors (10, 20, 44....99), until you get your result. Apply it for example using onTouch, on the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think your adding RGB values instead u can add ARGB value

i.e RGB is #112233
ARGB is #12112233

A means alpha first two digits will decide the transparency.
in RGB by default Alpha will be 100% means no transparency.

Try like this.